# Accessing a method variable from another class

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, pygame

So I've got something that looks like this

```
class MyClass():
    def someMethod(self):
        sprites = SomeClassInstance()

class MyClass2():
    def someMethod2(self):
         #The answer to the question goes here
```

Is there a way to access sprites from MyClass2()? And to top it off there is no statement like this

```
A = MyClass()
```

there is only this

```
A = MyClass().someMethod()
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? It seems likely that there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: If you provide us with more context, we might have a better answer for you

Comment: If you're not keeping the `MyClass` instance, you might as well write it as `myfunction()` instead of `MyClass().someMethod()`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept a solution, if you find any of them solves your problem. Feel free to ask further questions, if the answers are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Your sprites variable is local to `MyClass.someMethod`. Instead, attach it to `self` to make it accessible from outside the method:

```
class MyClass():
    def someMethod(self):
        self.sprites = SomeClassInstance()

class MyClass2():
    def someMethod2(self):
         #The answer to the question goes here
         myClass = myClass()
         myClass.someMethod()             
         sprites = myClass.sprites
```

If you want sprites to be a static variable, define it in the class body:

```
class MyClass():
    sprites = SomeClassInstance()
    def someMethod(self):
        pass

class MyClass2():
    def someMethod2(self):
         #The answer to the question goes here
         MyClass.sprites
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hacky... but if you just want to get stuff done your way, you can use a **global** variable:

```
SPRITES = None

class A(object):
    def setter(self):
        global SPRITES
        SPRITES = "mysprite"

class B(object):
    def getter(self):
        global SPRITES
        print SPRITES

a, b = A(), B()
a.setter()
b.getter()
```

But of course all instances of A and B will share one variable so this might not be what you want.